# Как реализовать цепочку команд в телеграм боте на aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlalchemy, aiogram

Мне нужно чтобы пользователь мог выбрать при командах /отдать и /выбросить от какого именно сообщения он хочет избавится. Иначе говоря, мне нужно чтобы в БД перезаписывалось значение owner. Либо на ID юзера которому отдают, либо на ноль. Использую ORM SQLAlchemy, и главный вопрос, какие способы есть реализовать выбор сообщений для выше описанных действий. Начеркал примерный код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['выкинуть'])
async def throw_out(message: types.Message):
    sesh = session.query(Message).filter_by(owner=message.from_user.id).all()
    for i in sesh:
        global i
        i = 1
        message.answer(i)
        i += 1

@dp.message_handler(text=['1', "2", "3"])
async def choose(message: types.Message):
    if i == 1:
        sesh = session.query(Message).filter_by()
```

Но, не знаю за что зацепится для фильтра, да и вообще код выглядит как-то не очень обнадёживающе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Абсолютно верно - код выглядит не очень обнадёживающе, один из случаев - использования глобальных переменных в локальной области видимости корутины, но это мелочи для ботов, и небольшого количества кода.
На самом деле ничего сложного нет - создаете стейт, и потом проверяете, что пришло в ответ в `await state.get_data()` (`message.text`), то есть пишите условие, где сверяете данные, и уже выполняете обновление/удаление из БД.

Если нужно создать цепочку в `aiogram` - почитайте про [конечные автоматы (FSM)](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/fsm/), это вторая ссылка в поиске в гугле. Подобная цепочка в `pyTelegramBotAPI`
работает проще и удобнее со стороны проектирования кода, но имеет свои недостатки.